Replacing an image with an image link
there are several images on a page like this
<img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg" alt="" />

how to use JQuery to change these images to links to these images and add an alt to each image as shown below


$("a").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<img src='" + $(this).attr("href") + "'>")
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://placehold.co/200"><img src="https://placehold.co/200" alt="image1" /></a>
<a href="https://placehold.co/200"><img src="https://placehold.co/200" alt="image2" /></a>



jQuery code that does the opposite, but I can’t change it

"but I can’t change it" - Why can't you?  What specific problem are you encountering?

I don't have enough knowledge to modify this code

You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

You're just need to reverse the tags in the jQuery.  And instead of href get src of image.


$("img").each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<a href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'><img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'></a>")
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://placehold.co/200" alt="image1" />
<img src="https://placehold.co/200" alt="image2" />




yes it works, thanks

Solution :
I had already done a similar action for a website, you can modify your code like this.
$("img").each(function(index) {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr("src");
    var altText = "image" + (index + 1); 

    $(this).replaceWith(
      $("<a>")
        .attr("href", imgSrc)
        .append(
          $("<img>")
            .attr("src", imgSrc)
            .attr("alt", altText)
        )
    );
});

This code will allow you to modify all the images that it detects in the code.
Results :
You should get the results as requested.
From
<img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg" alt="" />

to
<a href="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg"><img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/qwert.jpg" alt="image1" /></a>
<a href="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg"><img src="https://images4.imagebam.com/werty.jpg" alt="image2" /></a>

